# How to measure gridview before populating it?

Tags: android, gridview, responsive-design

How do I measure this gridview before populating it?

I have a girdview I am populating with posters. At first I was just working on the phone layout and now I am bolting on a tablet layout ... not exactly the best plan. Anyway, originally, the size of the views was set based on screen measurements, like these:

```
float[] screen = LayoutUtil.getScreen(mContext);

h = LayoutUtil.convertDPtoPixels(screen[1], mContext);
w = LayoutUtil.convertDPtoPixels(screen[0], mContext);
```

*In case it isn't obvious, here I should probably point out that this was in the activity, but now refactoring for tablet it is in the fragment that loads the gridview.*

I need to resize the views in the grid depending on the size and orientation of the tablet, and I whipped up this little snippet to do that:

```
if (null == convertView) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_poster, parent, false);
}

ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView;

int h, w;
{
    Configuration conf = getContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
    if((Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == conf.orientation) &&
        (600 <= conf.smallestScreenWidthDp)) {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        convertView.getLocalVisibleRect(r);

        h = r.height();
        w = r.width();
    } else {
        float[] screen = LayoutUtil.getScreen(mContext);

        h = LayoutUtil.convertDPtoPixels(screen[1], mContext);
        w = LayoutUtil.convertDPtoPixels(screen[0], mContext);
    }
}
```

Sadly, this doesn't work. The `h` and `w` values will be zero — probably because the gridview isn't populated yet.

So here's my layout:

#### layout-sw600dp-wide/content-poster-board.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="xyz.selfenrichment.robertotomas.popularmovies.PosterBoardActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_poster_board">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <GridView android:id="@+id/posters_grid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment_forecast"
            android:name="xyz.selfenrichment.robertotomas.popularmovies.MovieDetailsFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

That just gets included in the activity, which you probably don't need but:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="xyz.selfenrichment.robertotomas.popularmovies.PosterBoardActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_poster_board" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that in this case only the height was not being set .. and it happens to be a full height horizontal split. So .. I set I mixed the data for the LANDSCAPE orientation:

```
h = LayoutUtil.convertDPtoPixels(screen[1], mContext);
w = parent.getWidth();
```

Works perfectly!